# Symbolize points in the same shapefile differently

Tags: qgis, symbology, style

I was wondering if there is a way to edit the appearance of the points in the same shapefile. I have a shapefile with fifty points in which dead wild animals were found but 5 of them were positive to some diseases. I would like to put 2/50 points with another symbol, 1/50 with a different and so on for the 5 points.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, if you double-click the point layer (or right-click on the layer and select _Properties_), and go to the **Style** tab. Change the _Single Symbol_ option to another such as **Categorized**, **Graduated** etc. I personally like **Rule-based** as it allows you more flexibility in defining how points/lines/polygons are displayed by using formulas. But you can select and play with the other options to match what you seek.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Joseph i will play with your suggestion and see how it works. So far looks quite simple.

Comment: @ChrisW - Thanks Chris, the links Emlyn posted pretty much sums everything up so will leave it at that =)

Answer (score 2):

You could add a field to the shapefile that describes whether the dead animal - open the shapefile go to Properties>Attributes and add new columns. This could be a text field for 1 character (width) ("Y" or "N") or anything you like.

This video can help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuuFEq0a5gg

You can then change the style/symbology based on this attribute:
http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Emlyn. It is as useful as the answer of Joseph. The videos are very helpful. It works so far!